# maven/dojo best practice question

Tags: maven, dojo

thanks for any input and lessons learned.

Situation:  my company has a number of web apps.  all using dojo they all have custom profiled dojo builds that are checked into the web apps source code.  We have discovered that someone over the years has made some coding changes to these generated files in one or more of the web apps.  thank god the changes were insignificant.

what we want to do:  Is not check them into the web app source code.   We want to get them out of the maven repository at build time

My delema is what is the best way to build multiple versions of dojo and put them into the maven repository?  we want the :
group id to be com.mycompany.web
artifactId to be ApplicaitonDojo
version # to be the based on the dojo version.

I can use the command line build script to generate the build out dojo, zip it up, and then use mvn install or mvn deploy to put the zip into a repository.  BUT that is not really elegant or easy to remember what to do the next time they need to be rebuilt and deployed.  Especially if it is after I am no longer at the company.

I would like maven to build run the build against several different profiles and then deploy them the above group artifact version.  Since this is source classified as source.  Are assemblies the way to do it?

I have found postings on how to run the generate the profiled version of dojo but that only works if I am building the version from a web app.  I don't want to build a web app I want to run the dojo build script with some arguments.  Which plugin do I use to do that???

Frustrations vented  thanks for any suggestions

Any thought on how to do this, problems, suggestions on better ways of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I've seen it done is to add in dojo at compile time. This alleviates the need to store it in your own scm and also allows you to configure different profiles specifying which version of dojo you want to bundle. The following maven xml block shows how to add in dojo to a "js" folder in your artifact:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpackDojo</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.dojotoolkit</groupId>
                                <artifactId>dojo</artifactId>
                                <version>1.8.0</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <outputDirectory>
                                    ${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}-${project.version}/js
                                </outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is probably to let all clients download the [library](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/hello_dojo/) with their browsers at `runtime`.

`Google` have hosted quite a few [javascript libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) for us in a reliable and fast way.

I take this approach, rather than packaging up my own copy of the `Dojo toolkit` and serving it from my own servers.

The `Google` servers are probably faster, and my company's web cache will deliver everything after the first hit anyway.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I see that you're using modified version of Dojo. In that case, you would indeed need to use the Maven dependency plugin to unpack the zip file into your target directory:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html

However, I'd really question why you're using a modified build of Dojo! If your changes are really significant, why not try to contribute them back; that way, you can reduce the pain of distributing your own version and contribute to the Dojo community at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

there does not seem to be a best practice or really any lessons learned.

The simple brute force seems to be the easiest.  A script that builds all the archive(zip/jar/war...) and does a maven deploy seems to be the easiest.

Using assemblies is the elegant way.  my playing around... not so easy.  Not enough time to learn it the right way.  Must play around with it when my deliverable is done.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible: using bower/grunt to setup the dojo build and download dependencies on demand. An example configuration could be achieved via https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-dojo Then there is a maven grunt plugin: https://github.com/allegro/grunt-maven-plugin so you could trigger the build from maven and create for example a webjar (similar to webjars.org ) and use this as dependency in the server projects.

Advantages are:

- grunt delivers some "live" debug feature
- the clean separation of client and server code
- its not necessary to check any dojo code into your VCS

Disadvantage is probably the IDE support of such build processes. So usual prototyping would work better without build optimization, just including dojo webjars directly in the server project and code in the "public" folder.

In both cases, the first goal was to avoid checking in thousands of dojo files into Git.